# How do I activate code folding/collapsing for Javascript in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, javascript

For some reason, my Notepad++ is not showing the +/- buttons for collapsing code blocks in JavaScript.

This:

[image]

shows what I am seeing in my Notepad++ on my personal PC.

On my work laptop, there are +/- buttons between the line number and the code itself.

I'm wondering why these buttons are not shown on my personal PC?

Answer (score 1):

#### Notepad++ is not showing the +/- buttons for collapsing code blocks in JavaScript.

You need to enable a "Folder Margin Style", in your case "Box tree" to get the `+/-` style buttons.

1. Click menu "Settings" > "Preferences".
2. Select "Editing" on the left.
3. Enable "Box tree" under "Folder Margin Style".

[image]

4. Click "Close"

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]